# Python random forest dot

Tags: python

Trying to make a random forest, but I can't get past this first part of trying to make a vis. Error below.

```
from sklearn.tree import export_graphviz
pip install pydot
import pydot

tree = rf.estimators_[5]

export_graphviz(tree, out_file = 'tree.dot', feature_names = featureslist, rounded = True, precision =1)

(graph, ) = pydot.graph_from_dot_file('tree.dot')
graph.write_png('tree.png')
```

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] "dot" not found in path

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. What's your question exactly? Please [edit] to clarify. If you're looking for debugging help, you need to make a [mre] including working code (since `pip install pydot` is invalid syntax) and the [full error message with traceback](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146/4518341). It might also help to add any relevant tags for the field you're working in and libraries you're using. I'm not familiar with them myself. For more tips, see [ask].

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

```
from sklearn import tree
import pydot

...
tree_data = rf.estimators_[5]

export_tree_data = tree.export_graphviz(tree_data, feature_names=featureslist, rounded=True, precision=1)

graph = pydot.graph_from_dot_data(export_tree_data)
graph.write_png('tree.png')
```

The graph data from the function, `export_graphviv`, needed to be saved to a variable, now called `export_tree_data`. There it can be used in the function `pydot.graph_from_dot_data` to be converted to the correct format, then saved to a png.